# How do I print an array as a String from a method?

Tags: arrays, printing, return

I'm trying to print my array separated by pipes ("|"), but it keeps printing before the println statement in my main method. It should look like this:

90|0|-12|25|10412|445|-32|1

I've been messing with the return statement, but I can't think of anything else to do.

```
    static String arrayToString(int[] input){
    String toString = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if (i > 0){
            System.out.print("|");
        } else if (i == input.length - 1){
            System.out.print("");
        }
        System.out.print(input[i]);
     }
     return toString;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] testArray1 = {90, 0, -12, 25, 10412, 445, -32, 1};

    CommonArrayAlgorithms testingObject = new CommonArrayAlgorithms();

    System.out.println("Testing arrayToString");
    String arrayString;
    arrayString = testingObject.arrayToString(testArray1);         //<--- prints here
    System.out.println(" arrayToString returned: " + arrayString); //<--- should print here
```

My output is:

```
Testing arrayToString
90|0|-12|25|10412|445|-32|1 arrayToString returned:
```

When it should be:

```
Testing arrayToString
arrayToString returned: 90|0|-12|25|10412|445|-32|1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method you are outputting to the console with `System.out.print` where you should be adding to your `toString` variable.

Change you method as follows (keeping your current logic):

```
static String arrayToString(int[] input){
    String toString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if (i > 0){
            toString += "|";
        } else if (i == input.length - 1){
            toString += "";
        }
        toString += input[i];
     }
     return toString;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Just made an edit to it, I missed one `System.out.print`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling the method that prints the array before your title string, and also your method returns an empty string that you tried to store on another string and print it after your title.
So the solution for this :

```
System.out.print("your title: "+testingObject.arrayToString(array1));
```